# Organizing skype downloads in subfolders with contact names

Tags: data-transfer, script, skype, folder-action

I always wondered why skype don't put all my accepted downloads in subfolders with the name of my contacts!

If anybody have own solutions, share)

Answer (score 1):

So I made a script and saved it as a folder action:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    userFolder=~/Downloads/Skype/`xattr -p com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms "$f" | sed -e 's/0D//g' -e 's/.*\(5F 10\)...//' -e 's/00.*//'| xxd -r -p | sed -e 's@ (.*@@g'`
    mkdir -p "$userFolder"
    mv "$f" "$userFolder"
done
```

What it does:

1. gets `where from` field from file. In binary
2. deletes some binary-plist prefix
3. delete nulls at the end
4. creates string from binary with xxd
5. Gets the name of the contact from string.
6. creates a folder for that contact
7. moves file there.

If you have more elegant solution, I would be glad to see them :) 
P.S. if you didn't know about `where from` filed you can find it in `get info` for some finder items.

To categorize existing downloads you can also add service.

Comment: just so I understand... this will trigger after the file downloads automatically in the default "Downloads/Skype" folder, then your folder action triggers, running your script which then moves the file into the /username(d) folder, which your script creates if it doesn't exist - correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. But later I found that it can work incorrect with some nicknames. Be careful.