# How does Finder keep track of downloaded files' original URLs?

Tags: finder

When you open the info window, i.e. **Get Info**, of a downloaded file, Finder will show you the downloaded origin, called *Where from*. This information is there even the file is moved or slightly modified. How does Finder achieve this? Is it a feature of the file system?

Comment: I also found a similar question from a while ago: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110239/where-is-the-where-from-meta-data-stored-when-downloaded-via-chrome

Comment: Also, for developers, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584510/show-metadata-of-file-with-url. The documentation is here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/kmditemwherefroms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the metadata associated to a file.  Use xattr from the command line to see and manipulate the metadata.  Using ‘get info’ in the GUI is not equivalent, but should allow you to see some metadata attributes, including the originating URL.

Comment: Where is the metadata stored then?

Comment: @jackxujh it s a part of the file itself

Comment: Thanks! I got it! I can run `$ xattr -l cat_video.mp4` to show a list of attributes in both hex and text, or without `-l` to show only name of attributes. And other parameters with other usages as well!